# Magento 2 : How to Fetch Cms Block Count

Tags: magento2, admin, cms, cms-block

I want to fetch CMS Block count using identifiers in phtml.

How is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

Assume you have already created a block for your phtml and how to render a collection by custom Model, inside your block you can get the Blocks Collection by using `Magento\Cms\Model\ResourceModel\Block\CollectionFactory` class, as mentioned example below.

```
    protected $_blockcollectionFactory;
    public function __construct(
      ....
      \Magento\Cms\Model\ResourceModel\Block\CollectionFactory $blockcollectionFactory, 
      ...
      ){
      ...
        $this->_blockcollectionFactory = $blockcollectionFactory;
        ...
    }
        $collection = $this->_blockcollectionFactory ->create();
```

You can use this `$collection` for rendering count by Identifiers.You can add any necessary filters.

Comment: Hi krish at i95Dev, I followed so many of your answers, those are helpful to me. now i want to tell that, please write the answer with path also. that is very useful for beginners.

Comment: Hello @Krishati95Dev I want to fetch the blocks count for specific means like block_$i $i=1 to n.I want to count only for block_$i identifier And the phtml file is in the Magento _Theme/templates/html

Comment: Solved Thanks for the help @Krishati95Dev But the pattern are different